# Compute the sum of digits of very large integers via table and filtering

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

I am trying to find the smallest multiple of 2022 whose digits add up to 2022. So I built a table of such numbers, then trying to see which cases pass. This number will obviously have at the very minimum 2022/9 ~ 225 digits long.

```
Cases[Union[Flatten[Table[2022*n, {n, 10^225, 10^225 + 1000}]]], _?(DigitCount[#1].{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0} == 2022 &)]
```

So Mathematica cannot handle the computation. It just spins on....So I tried to break it into smaller sections of say 1000 wide as you can see. But I have to keep manually do this and forever!

Can I automate the section in another wrapper loop? Or is there a more efficient way of doing this?
Thanks

Comment: This exercise is not meant to be solved by brute force.

Comment: Of course it's not meant to.  But can Mathematica handle it? If the former implies no, then that's the answer.  If so, generalize what the limits of Mathematica are in terms of computation?

Comment: Something like this? `sumMatchedQ[n_] := Total@IntegerDigits@n == 2022;`, `i = 10^225;
While[Not@sumMatchedQ[2022*i], i++]`

Comment: sumMatchedQ is not recognized by Mathematica. what's missing

Comment: `sumMatchedQ[n]` is a user-defined function as it is clear from what @RohitNamjoshi wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if this is it, but here goes.  Start with 6 followed by 224 nines.  It's got 225 digits and adds up to 2022.  Let's check its divisibility.

```
guess = Join[{6}, ConstantArray[9, 224]];
Total@guess  (* 2022 *)

divisibleQ[list_] := Divisible[FromDigits[list], 2022]
divisibleQ[guess]  (* False *)
```

Okay, it's not divisible by 2022.  Let's change the 6 to 7 and change one of the nines to 8 then try again.
We'll test one 7 followed by all permutations of 223 nines and one 8.

```
Table[test = Join[{7}, p];
  {Length[test], Total[test], divisibleQ[test]}, {p, 
   Permutations[Join[{8}, ConstantArray[9, 223]]]}];
{Union[%[[All, 1]]], Union[%[[All, 2]]], Or @@ (%[[All, 3]])}

(* {{225}, {2022}, False}  *)
```

Okay, let's change the 7 to 8 and test the permutations of two 8's and 222 nines.

```
Table[test = Join[{8}, p];
  {Length[test], Total[test], divisibleQ[test]}, {p, 
   Permutations[Join[{8, 8}, ConstantArray[9, 222]]]}];
{Union[%[[All, 1]]], Union[%[[All, 2]]], Or @@ (%[[All, 3]])}

(* {{225}, {2022}, True} *)
```

Found at least one!  It has 225 digits.  The first digit is 8.  There are 2 other 8's and the rest are nines.

Use `Reap` & `Sow` to find the list of digits.

```
Reap[Do[test = Join[{8}, p];
   If[divisibleQ[test], Sow[test]],
   {p, Permutations[Join[{8, 8}, ConstantArray[9, 222]]]}];]
```

Are those the digits of the *least* multiple of 2022?  We didn't check for any multiples that start with 8, have one 7 and 223 nines.  Are there any others we should check?

Note:  Since we seek a multiple of 2022, we should only consider even integers. So, checking permutations that end in an odd digit is a waste of time.

#### Edit:

An additional bit of code will help interpret the results produced by the `Reap` statement shown above.  The `results` are calculated by putting `Last@Last@` in front of the previous `Reap`.  Then, the results are check to make sure they have expected number of digits and add up to a multiple of 2022.  The results are also split (using `SplitBy`, into groups of digits and the length of each group is output.

```
results = Last@Last@Reap[Do[test = Join[{8}, p];
       If[divisibleQ[test], Sow[test]],
       {p, Permutations[Join[{8, 8}, ConstantArray[9, 222]]]}];];

Through[{Length, Total, Length /@ SplitBy[#] &}[#]] & /@ results

(*  {{225, 2022, {1, 42, 1, 180, 1}}}  *)
```

The output means there are 225 digits, they add up to 2022, there is an eight in position 1, followed by 42 nines, 1 eight, 180 nines, 1 more eight.

Almost exactly the same code can be used to find the next smallest number whose digits add up to 2022.

Comment: Thanks very much @LouisB for all the effort for this! I assume I need to continue the practice for the other multipliers? .... And by the way the last command does not give me the digits...I get this:  {Null, {}}

Comment: @Steve237  Be sure that `divisibleQ` is defined before you execute the `Reap`.  Without `divisibleQ` I also get {Null, {}}. See the first section of code for the definition.  You should be able to extend this method.  I'm going add a small bit of code that makes the results easier to read.  Thanks for accepting this answer.